Can one come up with a standardized formula of an antenna?
I'm currently researching and designing an antenna with the operating frequency at 1 THz and over the past few months, I've developed a design that's somewhat novel and so I'm struggling a bit to find relevant papers that can help me explain my design of the antenna. It's similar and kinda not similar to the Bowtie antenna. I've been using CST Studio Suite to simulate the performance of this design and so I haven't got a single clue as to what makes my antenna perform as it's simulated (my method was just modifying what worked and looking at the performance of the parameters, such as S11, gain, e-field, etc).
This has made me wonder, is there a way to mathematically find out what's causing my design (the dimensions, the geometry and such) to emit such radiation pattern, achieve such gain, operate at the specified frequency, etc? I apologize if I sound like a complete buffoon as I didn't pick up a lot of things from my electromagnetics class nor my antenna and propagation class (both classes which I expected to teach me such ways are NOT as mathematically and scientifically rigorous as I expected it to be, a large factor I think being my lecturers have minimal clue and knowledge about it).
I tried reading Intro to Electrodynamics by D. J. Griffiths which somewhat explains the radiation phenomena (albeit using very rudimentary models, like dipole radiation but it uses two finitely small spheres being connected by a wire, the two spheres being separated at a distance) but I have no clue how to apply these principles to my antenna. I read that CST Studio Suite uses FDTD to calculate but the idea and implementation itself is pretty esoteric to me (maybe I'm just too lazy to research extensively enough, or CST is just stingy with their inner workings of their product, which is reasonable).
So to conclude, my questions are:

Is there a way to mathematically define the design of antenna and what its radiation will be like.
Continuing from the first question, if there is a way to mathematically define it, what are the methods and the steps to apply the principles to our antennas.


I'm not an antenna person but I would imagine that any sort of standardized formula would require a standardized (and/or non-trivial) model, which is not mentioned here. Saying something like similar and kinda not similar to the Bowtie antenna isn't a very helpful description. Perhaps there is a need for a review over basic fundamentals of boundary conditions and antenna parameters.

This may be rather late in your curriculum, or, give or take current and immediate future courses, but regarding motivation and proof, you might talk with the physics department, perhaps see if you can sit in take (or retake dept. equiv) classes on this part of EM theory.  It was my experience as well, EEs tend not to prove things much (or at all..!), which I find rather unsatisfying, and makes things harder to remember for those of us who tend to forget particulars but can easily generate them from principles. Whereas the physics courses are more likely to explain in the depth you require.

One of the ways to compute radiation from an antenna is to first find the current distribution along the antenna, from which you can compute the magnetic vector potential using a "simple" (read: nasty) integral. The electric and magnetic fields natural follow from taking the curl of the vector potential. In practice, this integral is done numerically. So it comes down to building up an intuition on how current distributions relate to the vector potential, and how to optimize for a given vector potential.

At 1THz (1000 GHz, 0.3mm wave length), antenna shape is only one of many factors in antenna design and performance.  The type and thickness of the metal, the material nearby, the air, etc.  You might see if the folks on the Ham Radio forum (of which I am one) can handle this, but it's not a frequency range that amateurs are likely to use.
